# compact set in a space of functions continuous in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, functions, metric-spaces, continuity

As it is known the set $\mathcal{B}=\{ f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} : f \mbox{  is continuous}\}$ it is not a metric space with the metric $d(f,g)=sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}\| f(x)-g(x)\|$ it can take the infinite value. But it is possible to make a decomposition 
$$\mathcal{B}=\bigcup_{f} (\mathcal{B}_f,d)$$
where $(\mathcal{B}_f,d)$ is a metric space and $\mathcal{B}_f=\{ h\in \mathcal{B}: d(f,h)<\infty\}$. I wonder if there is a "metric" (so it is with infinite values) $d^{\prime}$ in $\mathcal{B}$ such that

> If $K$ is compact in $(\mathcal{B},d^{\prime})$ then $K\subset \mathcal{B}_f$ for some $f\in \mathcal{B}$ and $(K,d)$ is compact (metric of $\mathcal{B}_f$).

I do not know much about metric take infinite values, but they said they do exist and that there is the solution. thank you in any suggestions or comments.